# Aiming in LibGDX using the mouse

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a game in libGDX and I am having trouble setting up the Bullet class. I am unable to get the projectiles to go to the mouse location.

I have tried to use Math.atan() to find the angle that I need to fire at but I couldn't get that to work. right now I am just using the distance to find velocity on the x and y-axis.

```
private static final int SPEED = 500;
private static Texture texture;
String path = "C:\\Users\\minicodcraft\\Downloads\\game\\core\\assets\\";
private float x, y; // starting position
private float xVelocity, yVelocity;
private float yPos; // the y position of the mouse input
private float xPos; // the x position of the mouse input

public Bullet(float x, float y, float yPos, float xPos) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.xVelocity = 0f;
    this.yVelocity = 0f;
    calcDirection();


    if (texture == null) {
        texture = new Texture(path + "Bullet.png");
    }
}

private void calcDirection() {
    float xDistanceFromTarget = Math.abs(xPos - x);
    float yDistanceFromTarget = Math.abs(yPos - y);
    float totalDistanceFromTarget = xDistanceFromTarget + yDistanceFromTarget;
    xVelocity = xDistanceFromTarget / totalDistanceFromTarget;
    yVelocity = yDistanceFromTarget / totalDistanceFromTarget;
    if (xPos < x) {
        xVelocity *= -1;
    }
    if (yPos < y) {
        yVelocity *= -1;
    }
}

public void update(float deltaTime) {
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
        x += xVelocity * SPEED * deltaTime;
        y += yVelocity * SPEED * deltaTime;
    } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
        x -= xVelocity * SPEED * deltaTime;
        y += yVelocity * SPEED * deltaTime;
    } else if (x > 0 && y < 0) {
        x += xVelocity * SPEED * deltaTime;
        y -= yVelocity * SPEED * deltaTime;
    } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
        x -= xVelocity * SPEED * deltaTime;
        y -= yVelocity * SPEED * deltaTime;
    }
}

public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(texture, x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code gives a velocity towards the mouse position from the player's position:

```
float diffX = mouse.x - player.x;
float diffY = mouse.y - player.y;
float angle = (float) Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);
float velX = (float) (Math.cos(angle));
float velY = (float) (Math.sin(angle));
Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(velX, -velY);
velocity.nor();
velocity.scl(magnitudeSpeed);
velocity.scl(deltaTime);
```

Then `velocity.x` is the x component of the velocity. Respective for y. No need to multiply by speed and deltaTime again, already done above.

Comment: thanks! right now I'm just doing y += velY * SPEED * deltaTime; and x += velX * SPEED * deltaTime; how am I supposed to use the vector to go to the location?

Comment: I've added one scale for the delta time. The components of the vector are your velocities. Add them to the position as before.